# Using Excel Countifs() with multiple Text criteria to determine student status

Tags: excel

I have student enrollment data from one cohort spanning twelve semesters. I'm creating tallies each semester to show how many students either, took the semester off, switched majors, or have no record of returning in any preceding semester. I'm having trouble coming up with a count of how many students took the semester off. So far, I have tried the following formula:

```
COUNTIFS(B2:B10,"=BIO",C2:C10,"=NONE",D2:F10,"=BIO")
```

In plain English, I translate this to mean:
Argument 1: if the previous semester they were enrolled as a BIO major
Argument 2: if this semester they are not enrolled and show up as NONE
Argument three: and a preceding semester they are enrolled as a BIO major count them.

***Here is an example mockup of my actual data:***

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Presumably you only count from semester 2 onwards?

Comment: You question is not so clear.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity. I am attempting to come up with totals for each semester and each major. The ones I am currently working on are students taking the semester off. If a student shows up under a different major after taking the semesters off, then they are counted under a different metric (being loss). If they show up under the same major, then they are counted as taking the semesters under which they were a NONE as off. Any students that do not return to enrollment within the twelve semesters are considered a drop.

Comment: Originally, I had hoped to use the countifs function. However, now I realize that each range on the countifs must be the of the same shape. I am left to conclude that countifs may not be an appropriate function.

Comment: @SNetz can you help us with required out sample.It will help is

Answer (score 0):

For `COUNTIFS` you don't need to add the equals sign, just write:
`=COUNTIFS(B2:B10,"BIO",C2:C10,"NONE",D2:F10,"BIO")`

This formula applies when your conditions are dependent on each other, for example, the students will count only when enrolled as a BIO major in semester 1 **AND** in semester 2 they are not enrolled **AND** in semester 3 they enrolled as a BIO major. In the example provided, there are 0 such cases.
`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I now see where my use of the countifs function would be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

if I have understood your question.

you can get it done by this way.

Crate New Column with the major Names and create count if Formula According

`=COUNTIF(G21:J21,"BIO")`  this formula is for BIO

Likely you can alter the formula major

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I attempted to add some clarity to my question in the comments above. It may be that my application of the countif function is not appropriate to get this answers I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following UDF which you place in a standard module. This can probably be tidied up.

Function `NotEnrolledCount`

Parameters:

Required `student`, Range. Cell where student name is e.g. `A2`

Required `semester`, Long, Semester to count up to e.g. `5`

Optional `sameMajor` Boolean, Default is True e.g. `False`

Example call in `N5`

```
=NotEnrolledCount(A5,7,TRUE)
```

Returns `1`

[image: Example UDF call]

The optional `sameMajor` allows you to specify if you want to count

`TRUE` where `Maj1, NONE, Maj1` **or** `FALSE` where `Maj1, NONE, Maj2`

**Note:** For some reason I have to press F9 to force UDF to update at times.

Here is code with a test sub to call the function to test the parameters.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

Dim myCount As Long

myCount = NotEnrolledCount(Range("A9"), 5, False)


End Sub


Public Function NotEnrolledCount(ByVal student As Range, ByVal semester As Long, Optional sameMajor As Boolean = True) As Long

    If semester = 1 Then
        NotEnrolledCount = -1
        MsgBox "At least two semesters must have passed"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim semestersRange()
    semestersRange = student.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, semester).Value

    Dim semesterNumber As Long

    For semesterNumber = 2 To UBound(semestersRange, 2) - 1

        Dim lastSemester As String
        lastSemester = UCase(semestersRange(1, semesterNumber - 1))
        Dim nextSemester As String
        nextSemester = UCase(semestersRange(1, semesterNumber + 1))
        Dim currentSemester As String
        currentSemester = UCase(semestersRange(1, semesterNumber))
        Dim semesterOffCount As Long

        If currentSemester = "NONE" And lastSemester <> "NONE" And  _ 
           nextSemester <> "NONE" And nextSemester <> vbNullString Then

            If sameMajor Then

                If nextSemester = lastSemester Then

                    semesterOffCount = semesterOffCount + 1

                End If

            Else

                If nextSemester <> lastSemester Then

                    semesterOffCount = semesterOffCount + 1

                End If

            End If

        End If


    Next semesterNumber

    NotEnrolledCount = semesterOffCount

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This seems to be an interesting method that I will need to give a try.

Comment: Let me know and I will tweak if necessary. It currently counts any maj-None-maj up to the semester you specify. If you only want the count  if specified semester is none and before is Maj and after is Maj it is easy enough to change. (Maj = Major)

Comment: Did this function  as expected?